# Django: environment variable for SECRET_KEY not working

Tags: django

I have `SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` in my `prod.py`, and `SECRET_KEY=secret_string` in my .bashrc

This will cause 502 error but if I set `SECRET_KEY="secret_string"`, it is working. How can I use environment variable to do this?

I'm starting gunicorn via `sudo service gunicorn restart` and I have a upstart script.

Here is the output of `cat /proc/<PID>/environ`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin^@TERM=linux^@UPSTART_JOB=gunicorn^@UPSTART_INSTANCE=^@
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bashrc` only affects bash login shells. Init scripts are not affected in any way by it.

You should copy the `export SECRET_KEY=...` line to the top of your init script.

Comment: Is adding `export SECRET_KEY=...` the only way to handle this problem? If I use `django-environ`, how can I `export` the environment variables in `.env` to the init scripts. Another question, as there is no "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" in the `/proc/<PID>/environ`, how gunicorn process knows the locations of setting files? The only explanation I think is `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.prod")` in wsgi.py. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, `setdefault()` is the explanation. Using `export SECRET_KEY` is not the only way (and I wouldn't recommend it: [environment variables should not contain secrets](http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful/), as they may leak). I usually store my secret key and my database credentials in a `localsettings.py` file. This file is unversioned (ignored by git) and is imported by my main `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Comment: I still prefer environment variables and I find another way: just like `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.prod")` in wsgi.py, I define .env in my repo and parse it in setting files. Anyway, thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do:

```
export SECRET_KEY=secret_string
```

in your `.bashrc`. If you just do:

```
SECRET_KEY=secret_string
```

It's only available in current process, but when you run django server/shell, the subprocess has no idea of this variable. `export` make the variable available in subprocesses as well.

Comment: I added `export` and then `source` the `.bashrc`, but it is still not working when I restart gunicorn.

Comment: @sac7e: `.bashrc` only affects bash login shells. Are you starting gunicorn from your shell?

Comment: Also, did you have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable defined? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: @sac7e: but *how* are you (re)starting gunicorn exactly? If you're using something like systemd, the environment variable won't be passed around. Check `/proc/<gunicorn-pid>/environ` and add it to your question

Comment: @ShangWang: I think it is defined in the wsgi.py, `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "config.settings.prod")`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: I use command `sudo service gunicorn restart` and I have a upstart script. I checked the process environment, there is no `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and also `SECRET_KEY`. I added the output of  context of /proc/pid/environ

Comment: I'm not sure. Worst case you do `source ~/.bashrc` in your upstart script. That would work.